# Linux Ubuntu 18.04 Error on loading screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I have a problem with Ubuntu 18.04. After using virtualbox and installing things such as virtualbox guest additions on my host, when my computer is starting, keyboard and mouse doesn't work, so I can't login to my computer.(However, I see the difference in the strength of the Wifi and I see changes when I plug/unplug battery)

virtualbox-guest was installed using: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms

Also, what I have noticed is that my ssd disc is now seen as a nvme0n1p2, not as a sda1 and I have no idea why did it change.

I have already created bootable usb and I have unistalled virtualbox(with the help of this https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=266548), still without any changes.

Do You have any ideas why is it not working? Or do You know where I should look for any logs, which could be a bit more helpful(I have already checked syslog, and boot.log, but without any strange logs).

Output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
arc4                   16384  2
iwlmvm                385024  0
mac80211              815104  1 iwlmvm
intel_rapl             24576  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
kvm_intel             237568  0
snd_soc_skl           106496  0
bnep                   24576  2
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  2
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    28672  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_realtek   114688  1
snd_soc_core          233472  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          40960  4
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
uvcvideo               94208  0
snd_hda_core           86016  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
8250_dw                20480  0
videobuf2_common       45056  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
hid_multitouch         24576  0
snd_pcm               102400  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
videodev              200704  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
joydev                 28672  0
btusb                  49152  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
ucsi_ccg               16384  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
media                  53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
iwlwifi               311296  1 iwlmvm
idma64                 20480  0
btintel                24576  1 btusb
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             557056  33 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
input_leds             16384  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
typec_ucsi             32768  2 ucsi_ccg,ucsi_acpi
serio_raw              20480  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
cfg80211              675840  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
typec                  45056  1 typec_ucsi
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
snd                    86016  21 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
int3400_thermal        20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
mei_me                 40960  0
ecdh_generic           28672  1 bluetooth
ideapad_laptop         36864  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
soundcore              16384  1 snd
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
acpi_tad               16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
overlay               110592  1
nls_utf8               16384  1
isofs                  49152  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  0
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 53248  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
i915                 1818624  11
nouveau              1863680  0
kvmgt                  28672  0
vfio_mdev              16384  0
mdev                   24576  2 kvmgt,vfio_mdev
vfio_iommu_type1       28672  0
vfio                   32768  3 kvmgt,vfio_mdev,vfio_iommu_type1
kvm                   626688  2 kvmgt,kvm_intel
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
ttm                   102400  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        180224  2 i915,nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
nvme                   40960  1
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   40960  0
r8169                  81920  0
drm                   479232  7 drm_kms_helper,i915,ttm,nouveau
nvme_core              94208  3 nvme
realtek                20480  0
i2c_hid                28672  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
hid                   126976  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
wmi                    28672  5 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop,mxm_wmi,nouveau
pinctrl_cannonlake     36864  0
video                  49152  3 ideapad_laptop,i915,nouveau
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_cannonlake
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 as your main operating system, and you have installed the Virtualbox application, you have installed the wrong packages, your computer is a "host" and should not have the "virtualbox-guest-utils", because it's not a guest. Uninstall the packages you installed from the terminal and reboot.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a TTY (non-graphical terminal), then uninstall the packages and reboot:

```
# sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-guest-*
# systemctl reboot
```

Comment: However I have already unistalled all of the packages

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsmod` to your question? (Don't run this from a USB stick, it needs to run in the Linux installation having the issue)

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure Ubuntu has a "safe mode" in Grub you can boot, what happens in that mode, does your input devices still not work?

Comment: I have pasted the output

Comment: Answer the second question too

Comment: Well, I figured out what to do. I had to reinstall all drivers to the keyboard and mouse and then change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and everything seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I had to create a Bootable USB with ubuntu, then when I tried it(not installing it)

I got to my disc using commands on this link:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=266548

Then I reinstalled input drivers(after connecting to the internet, I had to do it through cable)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

And changed line in file

```
/etc/default/grub
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
...
```

After this, everything starts to work. Both keyboard and mouse.